# Large delay when reading multiple serial devices using pyserial

Tags: python, gps, pyserial, uart

I'm trying to read data from more than one serial device using pyserial with the idea of syncing everything together. At the end I would like the code to:

```
- read serial from laser
- read serial from gps
- get a single string with [gps_reading, laser_reading]
```

The GPS has a refresh rate of up to 5hz
The Laser sends values on demand up to around 20 hz

In isolation, they all work fine and I get fast response time. However, when I try to read from more than one I get a delay which increases over time.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import serial
import time
import gps
import laser

#serial
def serialGeneric(device, baudRate):
    ser = serial.Serial(
    port=device,
    baudrate=baudRate,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    )
    return ser

#Device 1
gpsSerial = serialGeneric("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
gps.gps_init(gpsSerial)

#Device 2
laserSerial = serialGeneric("/dev/ttyUSB1",19200)

i = 1
start_time = time.time()

while i<50:
    dis = laser.lrf_getDistance(laserSerial)
    print dis
    pos = gps.gps_getData(gpsSerial)
    print pos

    i+=1


print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

gps and laser functions simply send the appropriate command to request data:
i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import serial

def lrf_getDistance(ser):
    i = 0
    while i == 0:
        ser.write("d\r\n")
        ser.flush()
        msg = ser.readline()
        try:
            msg = float(msg)
            i == 1
            return msg
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

When running the code, if I comment out 'pos = gps.gps_getData(gpsSerial)' and 'print pos' the "laser" device output is almost immediate. After uncommenting the "laser" output is extremely laggy.

In case it's relevant, I'm running the code on a desktop machine.

Can anyone please suggest how can I get rid of the lag?

- EDIT: I have changed the code to run both function in multiple threads. Following tutorial from tutorialspoint on multithreading in python.

The new code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import serial
import time
import threading
import gps
import laser

#serial
def serialGeneric(device, baudRate):
    ser = serial.Serial(
    port=device,
    baudrate=baudRate,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    #timeout=0
    )
    return ser

#Device 1
gpsSerial = serialGeneric("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)

#Device 2
laserSerial = serialGeneric("/dev/ttyUSB1",19200)

class myThreadGPS (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ser):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ser = ser
    def run(self):
        print "Starting GPS"
        gps.gps_getDataINF(self.ser)

class myThreadLAS (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ser):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ser = ser
    def run(self):
        print "Starting Laser"
        laser.lrf_getDistanceINF(self.ser)
# Create new threads
thread1 = myThreadGPS(gpsSerial)
thread2 = myThreadLAS(laserSerial)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

As mentioned in the comments, this "solved" the issue at hand. Unfortunately, I still don't really understand why this was needed.

Comment: How do you know that is the laser instruction the one that gets slow and not the commented&uncommented one? For what you are saying, it seems that the gps instruction is the slow one

Comment: Be aware that you are not setting any timeout, thus it will wait indefinitely until a value is obtained when reading

Comment: Hi Jalo, thanks for your comment, I just ran a test to check "GPS" and the reading are not lagging, GPS gives me time and I can see there is no lag. GPS is definetly slower (5Hz) against the "laser" (capable of sampling at 20hz).

Comment: WRT to the timeout. I have tried with and without and doesn't make any difference in this specific case.

Comment: There shouldn't be any added lag for putting together the laser and gps functions. You can try measuring times in all intermediate instructions to check in which ones is getting delayed

Comment: Hi Jalo, as per your suggestion, i've added a few lines to measure time. Time seems to be sync between devices, so they think they are reading within .2 of a second of each other. which is good enough for what I want. However, the lag on the "laser" device is still there.

Comment: I have replicated the problem by leaving out the GPS device and simply adding a small delay (via. time.sleep() ) even a 0.15 millisecond sleep is enough to get around 10 seconds lag on the sensor.

Comment: It is normal that there is an added delay when putting more work to do in the script. Your program is sequential, thus it will not begin a new instruction until the previous one has finished... you may use the multithreading library for improving your cycle time

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking into the threading library. I have now rewritten the script for it and it now runs correctly. Unfortunately, even tough that "solves" the issue, I'm still unsure I understand why it is needed. As the code was suppose to only request data upon request (every time I get a GPS reading) to make it easier to sync.  I will update the question to include the code with multi-threading. Thanks

Comment: The old way, the program had to wait for  the laser serial port before asking the gps serial port for data. As you are managing resources external to the Operating System, it is useful to do parallel instructions. For example, while you are waiting for data from gps port, you can ask meanwhile the laser port a new request... Moreover, if any synchronization is needed, there are several ways of doing it. Explain which variables and in which way you want to synchronize in the post.

Comment: Just did, I've added a description of what im trying to achieve in a few bulletpoints at the beginning. Thanks for your edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each thread, there will be the following synchronized resources:

- An event indicating when the cycle was ended, and the data received
- A shared variable, where the data to be printed is stored
- Another event indicating when can be started a new cycle. Each thread has to wait for this flag before beginning the cycle, and will be raised when both threads end their respective tasks.

I didn't check thoroughly the syntax of the following code, so there may some syntax errors. Basically, the threads synchronize with the main routine when they both read the serial port. When the main routine allows to start a new cycle, they read the ports in parallel once again.

```
class myThreadGPS (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ser, start_event, end_event, pos):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ser = ser
        self.start_event = start_event
        self.end_event = end_event
        self.pos = pos
    def run(self):
        self.start_event.wait()
        self.start_event.clear()
        print "Starting GPS"
        self.pos[0] = gps.gps_getDataINF(self.ser)
        self.end_event.set()

class myThreadLAS (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ser, start_event, end_event, dis):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ser = ser
        self.start_event = start_event
        self.end_event = end_event
        self.dis = dis
    def run(self):
        self.start_event.wait()
        self.start_event.clear()
        print "Starting Laser"
        self.dis[0] = laser.lrf_getDistanceINF(self.ser)
        self.end_event.set()

#Declare the used events
gps_end_event = threading.Event()
laser_end_event = threading.Event()
gps_start_event = threading.Event()
laser_start_event = threading.Event()
#Initialize shared variables
pos = [None]
dis = [None]
# Create new threads
thread1 = myThreadGPS(gpsSerial, gps_start_event, gps_end_event, pos)
thread2 = myThreadLAS(laserSerial, laser_start_event, laser_end_event, dis)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
#Start events initially set to True
gps_start_event.set()
laser_start_event.set()
while True:
    #Wait for both threads to end and reset them.
    gps_end_event.wait()
    gps_end_event.clear()
    laser_end_event.wait()
    laser_end_event.clear()
    #print the shared variables
    print pos[0]
    print dis[0]
    gps_start_event.set()
    laser_start_event.set()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try now and let you know. Just so that I understand. In the main loop. We set them first to false and then we set them to true? Is the default behavior for the event True?

Comment: By default they are set to False. Thus, the start events have to be set to True at the beginning, I will change that

Comment: I can now see both events running as threads, however, dis and pos always seems to be "none" and the threads are always reading values (not stopping for update values dis and pos, and not waiting). Could this be because of my function?

def lrf_getDistanceINF(ser):
 while True:
  msg = lrf_getDistance(ser)

Comment: @Khris They don't change because pos and dis are inmutable types, my mistake. A quick fix is to substitute them by a mutable type (a list, for example). I will change it, and sorry for the un-pythonic solution

Comment: I still don't know what im doing wrong. How do each thread knows your are setting a flag for it?, for example: how is laser_start_event = threading.Event() linked to myThreadLAS?. I can see the threads working, but still no data is being stored in the dis and pos variables. Thanks

Comment: @ Jalo, Thanks for the answer. I have made some changes, it now runs as it should. It turns our my mistake was that the run(self) function within the classes should have been running as loops. otherwise the values are not updated.